# Is there a way to export the data viewer in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, export

I am viewing the data viewer for the counter dictionary. The data is nicely put in 2 columns, but I can't seem to find an option to export as a CSV or to excel. Selecting all and copying doesn't work for some reason, only the rows that are currently on the screen are copied, even though all the rows are selected. I am running VScode on a Mac.

Comment: It's maybe not what you originally looked for/wanted, but what can be helpful in this respect is to use the xlwings package - something like:
    `import xlwings as xw
    xw.view(my_data_frame)`

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but it's impossible for now. This feature request is still open on GitHub. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1149) to join the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can export it using the debugger as a workaround.
`df.to_csv('/home/userx/df.csv')`